# Text is not visible in Note 3 on EditText or Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I write my layout perfectly and its running on each device perfectly but some how it's not working in Note 3. the Text on EditText and Buttons is Not Visible. i spend lot of time for this but nothing worked. some of the blog suggested to change the system font, But this didn't work for me. I also try to implement text color through Style.xml. but it also useless.

the below is my XML Layout

`

```
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#054482"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:weightSum="50"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" 
        android:layout_weight="18"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_for_mail_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_for_login"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"

            >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_weight="18"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_for_password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/et_for_login"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:weightSum="20"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="30"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
             >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                 >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:background="#054482"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="LOGIN"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:weightSum="10"
                >
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                />

            <CheckBox 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="REMEMBER ME.."
            android:textColor="#cb3904"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />

            <Button 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:text="FORGOT PASSWORD ?"
                android:textColor="#cb3904"
                android:textStyle="normal"                   
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Could you provide the xml of the layout ?

Comment: post your `layout's xml` code. Noone can't help you if you won't share your code

Comment: i know this layout is complex but it's flexible for each device but not working on Note 3. plz help me...thanx

Answer (score 0):

apologies for answering my own question. After done lot of research. I found that Note3 or Resolution of(1080 x 1920: xxhdpi) emulator don't show some specific fonts. I just Used "Typeface" in my code and made instantiate it with the "CALIBRI.TTF", that's way I'm not getting my text on my View's. So  I just removed Typeface instance and Now it's working perfectly